Hibernate Reverse Engineering meta tag attributes are visible in hbm2java ftl templates for auto-generated @Embeddable class?
I am using reverse engineering Hibernate (hbm2java) via Maven and hibernate.reveng.xml. One of my tables has a primary key consisting of two fields.
I would like to add a custom annotation to one of these fields.
An extract of my reveng.hibernate.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <table schema=“biva” name=“tbiv09_con_eve” class=“it.test.prod.entity.EventConnected”>
        <meta attribute=“test”>my value</meta>
    </table>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>

Since I use the meta tag to customize the generation of my entity files, using modified ftl templates and I don't have any problem, I would have liked to have done that, again.
But unfortunately I have a problem, I can’t display or check for the presence of a meta tag within an auto-generated class annotated with @Embeddable, for example EventConnectedId
If I add this line in PojoFields.ftl (from hibernate-tools-orm-6.6.1.Final.jar, under /pojo)
==><#if pojo.hasMetaAttribute(“test”)>OK!</#if><==

And try to check the generated entity EventConnected, I have correctly:
==>OK!<==

But, if I check EventConnectedId:
==><==

Is it a bug or an intended behavior?
Is there a way to use the meta tag in this context?
Thanks!
